# IntelliJ Maven integration

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I imported a Maven project into IntelliJ, but it seems like it's ignoring the `<configuration>` specified for the surefire plugin

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-Djava.endorsed.dirs=${settings.localRepository}/com/sun/metro/webservices-api/2.0.1
                </argLine>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/CacheStoreTest.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

When I run the tests from within the IDE, it picks up the webservices-api.jar bundled with JDK6 instead of the version from my Maven repository and it also runs the tests in CacheStoreTest even though I've indicated they should be excluded.

Comment: How are you running the tests within IntelliJ?

Comment: by right-clicking on a test folder and selecting "Run All Tests"

Answer (score 1):

It's a [known issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-52286), please watch/vote.